# Pasar valor de input hidden a otro

Tags: php, html

Cordial saludo. tengo lo siguiente, estoy tratando de insertar en dos tablas diferentes, de una forma muy "simple", ciertos datos. En la tablas`logistica_equipos_calibracion` tengo un campo que se llama`id` que funciona como un "indice", ya que es el mismo nombre de la PK de la tabla`logistica_equipos`, el problema es que cuando voy a realizar la inserción me dice que el campo id no puede quedar nulo.

```
if((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "form1")) {
    $insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO logistica_equipos (id, CB) VALUES (%s, %s)",
                  GetSQLValueString($_POST['id'], "int"),
                  GetSQLValueString($_POST['CB'], "text"));

    $insertSQL2 = sprintf("INSERT INTO logistica_equipos_calibracion (id_cali, id, CB, MEDIDA1, MEDIDA2) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)", 
                  GetSQLValueString($_POST['id_cali'], "int"),
                  GetSQLValueString($_POST['id2'], "int"),
                  GetSQLValueString($_POST['CB'], "text"),
                  GetSQLValueString($_POST['MEDIDA1'], "text"),
                  GetSQLValueString($_POST['MEDIDA2'], "text"));

      mysql_select_db($database_conexion, $conexion);
      $Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $conexion) or die(mysql_error());
      $Result2 = mysql_query($insertSQL2, $conexion) or die(mysql_error());
}

<input type="hidden" name="id2" id="id" value="id">
<input type="hidden" name="id" id="id">
<input type="hidden" name="MM_insert" value="form1">
```

Comment: Buenas tardes @AnderssonViveros. Convendría que añadieras una captura del error que te aparece. Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando estàs trabajando con bases de datos relacionales necesitas pasar a la tabla "hija" el id del registro al cual vas a relacionar, por ejemplo; si creas un registro en la tabla A se generarà un id (entero auto incrementable) en la tabla B guardas informaciòn vinculada a la tabla A por lo tanto necesitas el id generado en el primer registro (tabla A) PHP provee de un mètodo llamado `mysql_insert_id` el cual te regresa el id generado del registro que se guardò del ùltimo registro que insertaste, ese valor debes pasarlo a tu tabla B para poder crear correctamente la relaciòn.

Lee sobre el tema en este enlace:
http://php.net/manual/es/function.mysql-insert-id.php